# JavaScript countdown clock displays 4:04 as 5:14, seems to work the rest of the time

Tags: javascript, after-effects

This code is in an After Effects composition. I have a text layer that counts down seconds, and I'm feeding that into another text layer that displays it as a clock. The seconds counter is fine, it goes from 245 to 244 to 243 with no issues. The actual clock, on the other hand, goes from 4:05 to 5:14 to 4:03. I have no idea why.

Here's the code:

```
function padZero(n)
{
    if (n < 10) 
        return "0" + n; 
    else 
        return "" + n;
}
secLeft = (thisComp.layer("SecLeft").text.sourceText);
secLeft = parseFloat(secLeft);
mins = Math.floor((secLeft%3600)/60);
secs = Math.ceil((secLeft%60));
if  (secs == 60) {
    secs = 0;
    mins = mins + 1;
}
clockTime = mins+":"+padZero(secs);
```

EDIT: After some experimenting it seems I can get it to display almost anything except "4:04". As suggested in the comments I tried

```
clockTime = secLeft + "=" + mins + ":" + padZero(secs);
```

Which got me "243.24=4:04".

So I tried just removing the secLeft and equals signs, and it was back to 5:14. Then I tried:

```
clockTime = "a" + mins + ":" + padZero(secs);
```

Which got me "a4:04".

```
clockTime = 1 + mins + ":" + padZero(secs);
```

Gets me "5:04".

```
clockTime = 1 + mins - 1 + ":" + padZero(secs);
```

Gets me..."5:14" again.

What in the world is going on?

Comment: can you please add the full code ?

Comment: Please provide the implementation of `padZero`.

Comment: Edited to add the padZero function

Comment: @koberulz I just tried your code in the console with `244`, and it output `4:04` correctly as the clock time. Can you verify that you are supplying the right number to your code?

Comment: secLeft comes from another text layer in AE. I can see that layer, and the clock displays 4:05 at 244.02000, 5:14 from 244.00000 to 243.02000, and 4:03 at 243.00000.

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: I added in the secLeft bit. The text layer displays correctly so it must be a parsing issue if it's anything.

Comment: In which layer are you seeing `secLeft` having the correct value? Maybe the value is correct in its own layer, but when you import it into the clock layer, it's being read incorrectly.

Comment: `clockTime = secLeft + "=" + mins + ":" + padZero(secs);` try log out the value of `secLeft` at that very moment.

Comment: Well that's weird. That spits out "243.24=4:04", if I undo the change it goes right back to "5:14".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by closing the project to do something else, and reopening it to find "4:04" displayed on the clock.

Weird.